# How do I parse in go the returned JWT token from google OAuth 2.0?

Tags: go, google-api, jwt, google-oauth, google-signin

I am getting back a valid:

https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#CredentialResponse

after following the steps in:

https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/migration

i.e. this is all working:

```
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
    <div id="g_id_onload"
         data-client_id="YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
         data-callback="handleCredentialResponse">
    </div>
    <div class="g_id_signin" data-type="standard"></div>
```

and I it calls `handleCredentialResponse` with a valid CredentialResponse base64 encoded JWT.

```
function handleCredentialResponse(googleUser) {
  console.log(googleUser);
  var token = googleUser.credential;
  sendDataToRoute('/google/login', token); 
}
```

And I can do this in the backend in go:

```
  tokens := strings.Split(token, ".")
  base64Url := tokens[1]
  decoded, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(base64Url)
  jsonString := string(decoded) + "}"
```

and I'll get back some nice json with the user's name and email but the json is missing the very last closing `}`.

When i try and use:

```
func parseJwt(tokenString string) {
  secret := os.Getenv("GOOGLE_SECRET")

  token, err := jwt.Parse(tokenString, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
    if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodHMAC); !ok {
      return nil, fmt.Errorf("Unexpected signing method: %v", token.Header["alg"])
    }
    return []byte(secret), nil
  })

  if claims, ok := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims); ok && token.Valid {
    fmt.Println(claims["email"], claims)
  } else {
    fmt.Println(err)
  }
}
```

It always panics with invalid JWT error. I've tried calling `parseJwt` with the token before the `strings.Split(".")[1]` logic and after, and before base64 and after but nothing seems to parse it.

I have the code above that's adding the ending `}` in production and it's "working" but it's not really checking the secret to make sure the jwt is valid. How can I fix that?

Comment: gis is the JavaScript signin package why is this tagged Go lang?

Comment: because I'm trying to parse the result from javascript in go

Comment: But your server sided Go code is going to run before the client side JavaScript.  beyond that im wondering if the token you are trying to parse is in fact a JWT.   Have you tried doing a verify id token instead.

Comment: incorrect. sendDataToRoute('/google/login', token) make a POST to the server side go after the client side callback happens.

Answer (score 1):

ok found the answer! It has nothing to do with your oauth cred SECRET you made. You validate using the public google keys:

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs

from:

```
The ID token is properly signed by Google. Use Googles
public keys (available in JWK or PEM format) to verify
the tokens signature. These keys are regularly rotated;
examine the Cache-Control header in the response to
determine when you should retrieve them again.
```

above is the JWK format and you should hit that url and cache the json for some period of time defined in Cache-Control header.

Then here is working example of using those keys to validate the jwt:

https://github.com/MicahParks/keyfunc/blob/master/examples/json/main.go

```
import (
  "encoding/json"
  "log"
  "github.com/golang-jwt/jwt/v5"
  "github.com/MicahParks/keyfunc/v2"
)

jwksJSON := json.RawMessage(thatJson)
jwks, _ := keyfunc.NewJSON(jwksJSON)
token, _ := jwt.Parse(yourJwtFromGoogle, jwks.Keyfunc)
if token.Valid {
  claims := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)
  //claims["email"]  
  //claims["given_name"]
  //claims["family_name"]
}
```

and here is logic to cache that json for 24 hours:

```
func writeGoogleFile(file string) string {
  // https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token
  // cache-control: public, max-age=18702, must-revalidate, no-transform
  jsonString, code := network.GetTo("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs", "")
  if code == 200 {
    ioutil.WriteFile(file, []byte(jsonString), 0644)
    return jsonString
  }
  return ""
}
func getGoogleCerts() string {
  file := "/certs/google_jwt_oauth.json"
  fileInfo, err := os.Stat(file)
  if err != nil {
    return writeGoogleFile(file)
  }
  lastModified := fileInfo.ModTime().Unix()
  if time.Now().Unix()-lastModified > 86400 {
    return writeGoogleFile(file)
  }
  b, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
  return string(b)
}
```